# How deal with the const members in operator=?

Tags: c++

I have a class with some const members and I want to implement `operator=` but I can't assign value to the const members.

```cpp
class A {
public:
    const int value;
    A(int v) : value(v) {}; 
    A& operator=(const A& a);
};
```

How to implement `operator=` ?

I can implement copy constructor and call it from `operator=`, is it the only solution?

Comment: Well, generally if a member is `const`, it shouldn't be changed. That said, you _could_ use a `const_cast` … But this is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @ChrisMM ... and needs a bunch of `std::launder` trickery to not fall off defined behaviour.

Comment: @ChrisMM You **cannot** use `const_cast`.  Changing a `const something` with `const_cast` is straight up UB.

Comment: Why is `value` `const` if you want to change it?

Comment: The value never changes after the constuctor but I need to impement `operator=` for Boost serialization.

Comment: **Never** do that. In addition to potential UB if done wrong, **it makes the code harder to understand**. Obviously, if you make a member `const`, then user of the code would assume that it won't change. Stop writing bad code and trying to find way around that. There are no reason that a programmer in his right mind would ever do such thing.

Comment: @Phil1970 So using a const getter is the best way to access this variable outside of the class?

Comment: Using the `protected` access modifier will make your variable freely available to any member functions of the class as well as member functions of classes that inherit this class.

Comment: If it cannot be `const` (because of serialization) then yes, you should use a const getter and a private non const field. A serializable class is **obviously** not constant so any data that could be loaded from serialization is not constant too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The designer of the original class decided that `operator=()` is not supported and you should not try to implement it.

But, I suspect that the reason you want to implement it is because you are using it in another class and you want to implement `operator=()` for that class.

If that is true, I would hold `A` by pointer (or smart pointer) and reassign the pointer instead of trying to call `operator=()` on `A`.

You have to decide what kind of semantics makes sense for you with this pointer.

ADDENDUM: I am adding this part to explain something that I think you might not understand about C++.

With `A` from your question.

This code constructs an `A`

```
A a(3);
```

If you had a copy-constructor, this would call it

```
A b(a);
```

AND SO WOULD THIS

```
A b = a;
```

This line above is NOT `operator=()` -- it is an alternate syntax for the copy constructor.

Now, this is how we use `operator=()`

```
A a(4);
A b(5);

b = a; // <--- calls operator=()
```

Now, how can this possibly work if `b` has a const member variable that needs to change?

It can't, but ....

```
A a(4)
A b(5)
A* aPtr = &a;

aPtr = &b; // this is ok
```

So, if you need to refer to an `A` and one point and then you need to later refer to a different `A` -- use a pointer (or a wrapper, or a smart-pointer)

Comment: And what about calling copy constructor in `operator=()` ?

Comment: @MatthieuH: And how would that happen? A constructor creates a new object. By definition, if you're using an assignment operator, you already have an existing object. How do you plan to get the new object's value into your existing object?

Comment: Well if a class is used by other developers in other libraries as said in another comment, you should probably not modify the class if you don't really know the implication and cannot update existing code. If that is the case, then you should ask a senior programmer (in your company) what to do.

Comment: So, operator=() is supposed to change the left hand side.  I don't understand how calling the copy constructor will help change a const variable.

Comment: I added some more explanation

Comment: @LouFranco I assumed he was designing the class himself. If he's modifying someone else's class then he's better off inheriting the base class and overriding operators and functions as needed. In this case, the `const` variable declaration is still wrong and should be `private` or `protected` to avoid it being changed directly outside the class.

Comment: In a comment to another answer, they said it was an external library.  If it cannot be changed, I would not try to implement operator=() for it.  Just wrap it in something and use some kind of reference semantics that makes sense for the usage.

Comment: I think we need more clarification from the question's author before any further productive discussion can take place. @MatthieuH Is `value` a member of ***your*** class or a class ***someone else wrote***?

Comment: **So**, in my code I just need to copy constructor **and not** operator=() ? I think so.

Comment: **(1)** While `A b = a;` only call copy constructor in new standard, it was not always the case and thus it would not have compiled in older compiler because of the const member. **(2)** If OP does not need operator=, they it should only add copy constructor and leave `value` a constant public field. **(3)** Otherwise, the wrapper solution is preferable as it does not impact other code. **(4)** And if you still want to modify the class, then prefer updating all code that rely on the class over hacks against constness.

Answer (score 3):

`const` variables are a bit of an oxymoron. They are read-only generally cannot be changed without some voodoo magic and a bit of pointer shuffling. `value` is private (**EDIT:** now `protected`) anyway, so there's no way it can be changed without some sort of public function within the class. Just declare as a regular `int`.

```c
class A {
    protected:
        int value;   
    public:
        A(int v) //public constructor
        { 
            value = v; 
        }

        A& operator=(const A& a) //public operator override
        {
            if(&a == this) //check for self assignment
                return *this;
            //do actual assignment
            value = a.value;
            return *this;
        }
};
```

Comment: Yes but in my code the const value is not private and if the value is modify the class return wrong result. Moreover the class belongs to an external part of a library thus accessible by other developer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. This answer *should* be correct based on the information you've given us. If there is something wrong with my answer, then point out the factual errors, or update your question to have more information so I can update my answer to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthieuH I think I see where you went wrong. You're looking for the `protected` access modifier.

Comment: Yes, using a const getter is the best way to access this variable outside of the class? Because doing `a.getValue()` is more complicated than just doing `a.value`.

Comment: Yes, an accessor function is the only way to get the value of a `private` or `protected` variable in a class. Moreover, the mutator function is how you should modify the values of the class's member variables. However this is beyond the scope of your question. Your `operator=()` function is for the class as a whole, not the individual member variables.